# Android : Firestore component is not present

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have seen the existing questions raised for `flutter` projects but those solutions don't work for `native` Android development using the android studio.

Here's my project level Gradle `project/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url  "http://dl.bintray.com/piasy/maven"
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App-level gradle has the following `app/build.gradle`

```
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
```

and `gradle.properies`

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Initialized `Firestore` in application

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

In my activity

```
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
                .build();

        db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```

I'm using the latest gradle version and firebase libraries, so why do I get `Firestore component is not present.`? Couldn't find proper answer or solution on this.

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wasted 30+ days in this just because firebase documentation doesn't detail anything about this.

Seems like `google` has changed the sdk. You need to extend `ComponentDiscoveryService`. Add the below code to the bottom of your android manifest application.

The below configuration will work for the following services

1. Firebase Database
2. Firebase Analytics
3. Firebase Firestore
4. Firebase Auth

```
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar"/>
        </service>
```

Comment: You Saved my day! Thanks @silverFoxA

Comment: This is added there automatically by manifest merger.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from June 2019 update, you have to upgrade to AndroidX and change compileSdk to 28 to use the new versions of libraries.

From [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019):

> **June 17, 2019**
>   *Warning: This release is a MAJOR version update and breaking change.*
>   The latest update to Google Play services and Firebase includes the following changes:
>
> Migration from Android Support Libraries to Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries. Libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:
>
> **Upgrade com.android.tools.build:gradle to v3.2.1 or later**.
>   **Upgrade compileSdkVersion to 28 or later**.
>   **Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX)**; follow the instructions in [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Your gradle version is fine, as well you play services version. Make sure you are using compileSdkVersion 28 or later along with AndroidX and *not support library artifacts like AppCompat*.

Comment: All that is fine, compiledSdkVersion is 28

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `google-services.json` file in the app-level directory of your app

[image]

Also, you have added the Google Play services Gradle plugin as given below. You can find more from the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-config-file)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

// Add the following line to the bottom of the file:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Play services Gradle plugin
```

Comment: All that is there but I think I have the service json inside product flavour as I have multiple product flavour