# Xamarin Android FirebaseDatabase null pointer exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am having an issue in my Xamarin Android project, where I'm getting a NullPointerException: 'Firebase Database component is not present'.
I have recently picked up on Xamarin Android hence my knowledge is a bit limited.

The following image is a code snippet from a static Helper class, called in an EventListener class.

Any help regarding this issue?
Also all dependencies are upto date.

[image]

Comment: Check you connection string.  There is something wrong with the connection string or the driver that is specified in the connection string is missing.

Answer (score 1):

So after long search, I just decided to update my Visual Studio and android SDK, and the issue was no more

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Google has changed the SDK and you need to add some things to `AndroidManifest.xml`. Check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57546293/12502168) for the lines you need to add.
Credit to [silverFoxA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4578454/silverfoxa) for the solution.

Comment: I also saw suggestions to extend the `ComponentDiscoveryService` to AndroidManifest but I'm still having the same issue